# Relative Layout ignoring setMargin()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to nest a `RelativeLayout` inside of a `LinearLayout`, and give the `RelativeLayout` a margin that spaces it's edges away from the edges of the `LinearLayout`. So far I have this:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.conversation_view_layout, this, true);

this.setLayoutParams(new MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
int tbm = AllConversationsActivity.topAndBottomMargin;
int lrm = AllConversationsActivity.leftAndRightMargin;
((MarginLayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(lrm, tbm, lrm, tbm);
this.requestLayout();
```

Which, if I'm reading the API correctly, should set the margin of the RelativeLayout to the numbers specified. It isn't doing so at all, but instead seems to be simply ignoring the `setMargins()` entirely.

Also, here's my xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/conversation_picture"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/conversation_person"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/conversation_picture"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/conversation_length"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/conversation_first_line"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/conversation_picture"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/conversation_last_time"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/conversation_first_line"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

I have a small suspicion that these views are forcing the `RelativeLayout` edges to the parent edges when they make their alignment calls.
Does someone know what has to be done to get these margins to set? Or maybe there's a better way to do this entirely?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edit:**

You are using MarginLayoutParams instead of LinearLayoutParams.
NOTE: if you set LayoutParams on a layout container, you will need to use the parent's type.

So if you have a LinearLayout that contains a RelativeLayout, you need to set LinearLayout.LayoutParams on the RelativeLayout.

```
// NOT WORKING: LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
int tbm = AllConversationsActivity.topAndBottomMargin;
int lrm = AllConversationsActivity.leftAndRightMargin;
params.setMargins(tbm, lrm, tbm, lrm);
setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: If this was the problem he would have been getting a class cast exception. MarginLayoutParams are a super class of LinearLayout.LayoutParams, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and so on. Besides what setLayoutParams() actually does is to keep the params in a member field and call requestLayout() so only one of these calls should be hapenning(either requestLayout() or setLayoutParams() but not the two together)

Comment: Entreco, you turned out to be exactly right, it was because I was creating the wrong owner of the params, but the implementation you put was slightly wrong. Here's the code that ended up working:

    `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  int tbm = AllConversationsActivity.topAndBottomMargin;
  int lrm = AllConversationsActivity.leftAndRightMargin;
  params.setMargins(tbm, lrm, tbm, lrm);
  setLayoutParams(params);
  requestLayout();`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this does not work for me. I tried this in my extended LinearLayout's constructor. The margins don't show up at all no matter what dimensions i provide. What could be wrong?

Comment: setLayoutParams(params) already calls requestLayout() by itself.