# Setting margin programmatically not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layoutparams

In my app I'm creating a RelativeLayout programmatically and setting topMargin. On Nexus 5X, margin is set, however, on LG G4, there is no margin.

```
public static PictureView createPictureView(final Context context) {
    PictureView newPicture = new PictureView(context);
    int pictureHeight = context.getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.picture_view_height);//200dp
    final LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            pictureHeight);
    params.topMargin = context.getResources()
            .getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);//16dp
    newPicture.setLayoutParams(params);
    return newPicture;
}
```

Parent layout is always LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pictureContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
```

I've tried [setting LinearLayout divider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259467/in-android-how-to-make-space-between-linearlayout-children), but it doesn't work on both devices.

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771106/setmargin-programatically-not-working-correctly-for-relativelayoutparams),suggesting to use parent's LayoutParams, but it does not apply here, since I'm already using correct LayoutParams.

Comment: Have the same issue. Have you found any solution for this? @Marius Kaunietis?